# Is it possible to use GnuPG in a Shared Folder?

Tags: c#, .net, gnupg

I have the current problem that I'm using GnuPG for encrypting my data, I have the gpg.exe on a shared folder over a network, also I'm using this API on C#:

https://gpgapi.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20to%20Encrypt%3f

On my software in this part I set the path to the gpg with the address to the Shared Folder where I have it.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    GpgInterface.ExePath = "\\PATH\To\The\gpg.exe";
    ...
}
```

(Code is just an example of how I'm doing, not actuall code)

I don't know why, if it's on a Shared folder over a Network I can't find the keys that are allready registered in there.

If I logon as the user who has the shared folder (the original) and I run the `gpg --list-keys command` it does find them. But from a remote user it doesn't.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Do you get correct output on command line?

Comment: Miserable: Yes, when I logged in, lets say, as "Admin", when I run the command it does showed me the keys. But when logged in as "User" in the command line after running the command it doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've allready found a solution, I had to change the home directory setting it as a shared folder over a network, so my keys will save to that address.

http://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2008-January/032437.html

The solution I've found is in that URL, I had to create a new enviroment variable so the GPG will look for the homedirectory on that variable.